# How does DLC address relate to the MAC address?

Tags: networking, ethernet, mac-address, packet

The Network Engineering help seems to negate this question in their forum.

A MAC address is hard coded, all 6 bytes, agreed? The DLC seems to be a variable address of 3 bytes in front of the OUI depending on the type. The DLC cannot be hard coded to be variable but it also seems to be used as a MAC address for addressing purposes. This seems to be at cross purposes, as opposed to a broadcast address which is straight forward and not related to the physical addressing issues here.

Here is a capture from [MAC Address Types](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6sycNzZu8Yw) on YouTube that is the source of my train of thought, such as it is.

[image: Packet Capture image capture]

I looked up structure and coding of LLC addresses at the IEEE web site and it seems to be what is referred to by the first three bytes of the DLC in the video, and at the risk of repeating myself is variable which is the source of my confusion. I noted the subject of Group Address assignment but don't believe it is relevant here.

I hit my link ceiling trying to link the capture from my Packet Tracer where I see the LLC broken down in a simulation from an STP Ethernet 802.3(as opposed to Ethernet II) packet. I am missing something here relating the DLC variable addressing to a MAC fixed addressing in apparently the same context.

Question: What separates the use of DLC vs MAC addresses and why, eg. Ethernet 802.3 vs II? I don't know how else to pose my general confusion on apparently conflicting uses. I have gone to a great deal of effort to provide references to try make this clear and may find it necessary to clarify with your help.

Thank you

Comment: I don't think I've _ever_ heard this term, but if it expands to "Data Layer something", then it might be that a MAC address is a specific _kind_ of a DLC address? (Not all networks use 6-byte MAC's/EUI48's; it could be an EUI64 or even something entirely different for non-IEEE protocols.)

Comment: It appears that DLC is a less common name for the entirety of the OSI/DOD Layer 2, without regard for the L2 protocol in use. Its important to note that the frame in your picture is Cisco Dynamic Trunk Protocol which implements the 802.1Q or Cisco ISL specification at Layer2. As a VLAN Tagging mechanism, additional addressing information about VLANs in question is important. Also note, from your youtube link, the destination in your pic starts with an odd numbered byte, so its a multi-cast frame.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#Unicast_vs._multicast The OUI for the destination mac in a frame varies dependent on whether the frame is Unicast, Multicast, or Broadcast.

Comment: Expanding a seldom-used Three Letter Acronym at least once helps to make a document more accessible to a wider audience.

Comment: @Frank Thomas you hit the nail on the head...the destination, which is the MAC address, yes?...and if it was not multi-cast the address would begin differently. 

The opening screen of the youtube video i linked to in my original post shows this and began this quest.

If these addresses can vary with message type, how can they represent the MAC address which is unchanging?

Tx all!

Comment: multicast and group destination mac addresses are different than standard unicast destination addresses. since they don't target a specific machine, they instead either use ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff or a group address that the switch knows, but they are still destination hardware addresses that the switch can interpret, so they are MAC addresses, they just don't identify a single nic. Multicast groups are created programmatically, so their addresses are dynamically assigned.

Comment: They don't identify a single NIC....that was my assumption, or understanding, that all 6 byte hex dest or source addresses did represent the actual NIC. So I understand now they don't and I'm not crazy. So the last three bytes are the OUI. What if there are multiple similar machines with identical OUIs in the path of the dest. address that is represented in the Ethernet header? Unicast is one, so how does it identify the correct device without the unique MAC address?

Comment: " how does it identify the correct device without the unique MAC address" It use the other half of the MAC address (NIC specific) which is intended to be unique for a particular set of OUIs (but there have been instances where it is not - eg manufacturers mistakenly, or ignorantly making devices with identical NIC specific MAC address parts)

Comment: That is what I would have thought until I saw this video which shows the first byte at least eg. 00:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx of the address, which I expected to hold the NIC specific info, as a Type designation. I know I'm still missing something here but I can't see it.

Comment: well, first, the first byte of a multicast or broadcast address will be of odd value (as decimal defines even/odd) so a MAC that starts with FF is always a broadcast, and one that starts with 01/03/05/... is always multicast. That tells the switch immediately that the frame is not meant for a specific nic. it will then look up the multicast groups it knows, and send the frame out all ports that have at least one of the unicast MACs that is part of the multicast group. only Unicast addresses use a vendor code (cause no one manufactured a nic) so the OUI can be used for any other purpose.

Comment: Just to be clear, 'vendor code' is the other half of a MAC, and not another term for the OUI?....just making sure. (this is how the ADD mind works, so forgive me the apparent minutia) You are helping. I am focusing on multicast groups now and have already spent a few hours connecting the dots and that this addressing issue is solely at the ethernet frame. Still working on it....

Comment: @FrankThomas I accept the facts of what happens as already discussed regards the LSB of the first octet. From Organizationally_unique_identifier wiki & MAC_address wiki there is a good discussion of Unicast and Multicast.

Now...so if the Globally Unique MAC has a bit changed for Unicast where and how is the decision made to do this, and how does the receiving node or even the switch, identify the correct device(as opposed to mulitcast with defined groups)? Is that a fair question?

Also, how does a node or NIC join a particular multicast group, if I understand this correctly?
Thank you

Comment: @donald-duck interesting edit...still a newbie and cannot remember if I saw an ability to insert image vs a link then, or if I needed more reputation at the time to do it. I find that very frustrating being limited in posting.

Answer (score 3):

#### What separates the use of DLC vs MAC addresses?

They are the same thing, when used in the context of Ethernet networks.

- DLC is an abbreviation for **D**ata **L**ink **C**ontrol.
- MAC is an abbreviation for **M**edia **A**ccess **C**ontrol.

In IEEE 802 standard networks - which include Ethernet - the DLC address is usually called the MAC address.

> Every network interface card (NIC) has a DLC address or DLC identifier
>   (DLCI) that uniquely identifies the node on the network.
>
> Some network protocols, such as Ethernet and Token-Ring use the DLC
>   addresses exclusively.
>
> Other protocols, such as TCP/IP, use a logical address at the Network
>   Layer to identify nodes. Ultimately, however, all network addresses
>   must be translated to DLC addresses.
>
> In TCP/IP networks, this translation is performed with the Address
>   Resolution Protocol (ARP).
>
> For networks that conform to the IEEE 802 standards (e.g., Ethernet),
>   the DLC address is usually called the Media Access Control (MAC)
>   address.

Source [DLC](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/D/DLC.html)

Comment: definitions of MAC and ARP don't answer my question as posed. Note my comment to Frank Thomas to explain why. If anyone marks it as answered they have missed the point entirely.